# How would you limit http upload speed in Android?

Tags: android, upload, limit, bandwidth

I'm using [Apache HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html) APIs in Android and do not see any way to limit upload bandwidth. Is there a good way to do this?